# Do I need injection, throttle body, and upper intake cleaning?

Tags: toyota, camry, fuel-injection, throttle-body

I have a 2014 Toyota Camry with 52k miles.

The last 2 times I've gone to the dealership for regular oil change and maintenance checkups, they've tried to get me to do an injection, throttle body, and upper intake cleaning.

The articles I've seen online seem to suggest these things aren't really necessary, and I don't see them mentioned in my owner's manual maintenance guide:

- https://www.cartalk.com/blogs/dear-car-talk/mechanics-throttle-body-recommendation-legit
- https://www.testingautos.com/car_care/throttle-body-when-to-service.html
- https://www.cars.com/articles/do-fuel-injectors-need-periodic-cleaning-1420680479051/
- https://www.kbb.com/car-advice/articles/do-you-need-an-injector-flush/#zipo=6ef7f464-166f-4d32-a6bc-fdd3a3eb2896

I have noticed when I try to accelerate quickly sometimes it takes a second for the acceleration to kick in. **Should I do the above maintenance suggestions?**

Comment: What engine do you have? Previous gen corollas (iirc 1.8l) have issues with fuel injectors clogging causing a lean condition. Though I’ve not seen it on previous gen camrys. Nor on the newer models yet.

Answer (score 0):

Dealerships all have the same hard sell tactics.  They used to say to change your shock after 24000 miles.  The service your talking about you can do yourself and save a bunch of money.  Also, like I mentioned to another, use an Ethenol treatment like Amsoil Quickshot to clean the garbage in your fuel system due to Ethenol in the fuel. Or just use a mild fuel injector cleaner like "Gumout".  Does wonders.

Comment: Or just run premium gas and never worry about it again.

Comment: I use premium ( more aromatics = strong solvents) in my 2011 Murano. 93,000 , never cleaned, never a problem. Actually never serviced other than change oil.